# How do I exclude elements whose ID ends in a certain suffix using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery function:

```
$(this).change(function(){
  alert('I changed. ID: ' + $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

I need the alert to fire **except** when the id name ends in `-0`. I think I should be using the `$=` operator. I cannot figure out how to make it work.

Comment: When I see questions like these I just think, jQuery encourages too much ad hoc and costly querying of the dom, and not enough planned organization of the elements of one's UI

Comment: @George - While sometimes true, there are also times the front end developer has no say in the generated content, just be aware of those cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selector should use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) combined with [attribute-ends-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) (`$=`) look like this:

```
$(":not([id$='-0'])")
```

It's better to have *something* in front of that so it doesn't run against every element, a class or an element tag, etc, like this:

```
$(".myClass:not([id$='-0'])")
```

Comment: Can I do this? $(this :not([id$='-0'])) ?

Comment: @resonantmedia - If you you to find element *beneath* `this`, do this:   `$(this).find(":not([id$='-0'])") ` if you want to filter the current set use `.filter()` instead, like this: `$(this).filter(":not([id$='-0'])")`.

Comment: Maybe it would help if I give more details, because this is still not working. Here is the whole function.

<pre>
 var divId = 'GPA-Entries';
 $("#" + divId).find('select').each(function(){
  $(this).change(function(){
         if($(":not([id$='-0'])")){
    alert('I changed. ID: ' + $(this).attr("id"));
   }
  });
 });
</pre>

It is still returning the alert regardless. Even when the div id is: certificationArea-0

Please help.

Comment: @resonantmedia - I think it would be easier to filter and just not attach the change handler to those elements, like this: `var divId = 'GPA-Entries'; $("#" + divId ' select:not([id$='-0'])').change(function(){ alert('I changed. ID: ' + this.id); });`

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
$("id:not[id$='-0']");
```

with an if statement.